# How to set SignalR Group Id on angular app with @microsoft/signalr

Tags: c#, angular, azure-functions, signalr

So i am using an Azure Function and an Azure SignalR Service. I am trying to broadcast messages to the Angular client only for specific groups.

My code in C#:

```
[FunctionName("negotiate")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
    [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
    [SignalRConnectionInfo(HubName = "broadcast")] SignalRConnectionInfo signalRConnectionInfo,
    ILogger log)
{
    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult(signalRConnectionInfo);
}

[FunctionName("message")]
public static async Task<IActionResult> Message(
   [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
   [SignalR(HubName = "broadcast")] IAsyncCollector<SignalRMessage> signalRMessages,
   ILogger log)
{
    string requestBody = new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEnd();

    await signalRMessages.AddAsync(new SignalRMessage()
    {
        Target = "notify",
        GroupName  = "myGroupName",
        Arguments = new object[] { requestBody }
    });

    return new OkResult();
}
```

my signalR service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as signalR from '@microsoft/signalr';
import { HubConnection } from '@microsoft/signalr';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignalRService {
  private hubConnection: HubConnection;
  messages: Subject<string> = new Subject();
  constructor() { }

  init() {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl('http://localhost:7144/api')
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

    this.hubConnection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
    
    this.hubConnection.on('notify', (data: any) => {
        this.messages.next(data);
    });
  }
}
```

How can i set the group in the HubConnection in order to send the SignalRMessages only to the client users with the specific group?